# is this considered a bug in php offsetget method

Tags: php

example with an object that `extends` an object that `implements ArrayAccess`

if I try to access a variable in an object way both `_get` and `offsetget` are called, but 
if I access it array like only `offsetget` is called

I don't seem to have a problem (I get the value from _get returned, if there is one)
,but the offsetget method could potentionally mess things up

Anyone experience with this

```
class Container implements ArrayAccess {

    public function offsetGet($key)
    {
      $this->t .= "call magic offsetGet with $key<br>";
      return $this->make($key);
    }
}
class Application extends Container{
   protected $t="";
    public function __get($key)
    {        
        $this->t .= "call magic _get with $key<br>";
        return $this[$key];
    }
}


$e = $app->t;
// $e = $app['b'];
// echo $app->t;
var_dump($e);
```

Comment: Why don't you provide your script !

Comment: I'ts laravel application class wich extends container

Comment: Sorry man, I don't know `laravel`

Comment: Please provide a *minimal, self contained* code sample that demonstrates the problem. If you assert you may have found a bug, always supply code, don't just talk about code.

Comment: ok, that would be easyer, sorry

Comment: Why would this be a bug? `->b` accesses an *object*, `['b']` accesses an *array*. `ArrayAccess` lets you access objects as arrays, but `__get` does not do the reverse.

Comment: but if I want to just get a variable and not trigger a make method, the _get ,( ->b ), would trigger both...just seems redundant. The reverse, ( calling ['b'] ), does not trigger the _get method.

Comment: I did read the docs, someone saying they play well together, but I think you will have to set a flag if you don't want both functions to be called, but I appreciate any insight

Comment: Is it possibly triggering both because you are calling `$this[$key]` inside `__get`...?!

Comment: from the docs This (offsetget)method is executed when checking if offset is empty(). http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/arrayaccess.offsetget.php. As you can see, not much info;

Comment: ok, sofar..I have concluded that the use off _get and offsetget are both used to access the same thing/method and it should be used with caution. You can access protected properties, but offsetget get's called also, wich could potentionally cause a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `deceze` points out, this is not PHP calling both magic methods at the same time, they are both explicitly called in your code:

1. You access a non-existent property, say `$app->foo`
2. This will call `Application::__get` with `$key = 'foo'`
3. That includes the line `$this[$key]`, which will resolve to `$this['foo']`
4. `$this` is an object being accessed as an array, so causes a call to `Container::offsetGet` with `$key='foo'`

If you just access `$app['foo']` directly, `Application::__get` is never called, because you are jumping straight to step 4.

Similarly, if you comment out the `return $this[$key]` line in `Application::__get`, there will be no call to `Container::offsetGet`, because that is the line that is invoking the `ArrayAccess` magic.

Comment: many thanks, unbelievable that one can read straight through it, also missed the exclamationpoint in @deceze comment.

Answer (score 0):

As manual states:

```
__get() is utilized for reading data from inaccessible properties.
```

Issuing the following will create a public properties named 'b':

```
$app->b ="hh";
```

From now on if you access $app->b the __get() method is no longer called

Comment: I changed my test sample